# Sefarim on Hilchos Mikvahos

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mikvah-ritual-bath

I'm learning Hilchos Mikvahos (YD 201). I'm learning Tur, Bais Yosaf, Shulchan Aruch with the Nosa Kalim. Does anybody know of any good sefarim on mikvoas.

Comment: https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?193877&

Answer (score 4):

‘Afikei Mayim’ is *the* sefer which is a collection of all relevant core material beginning with Toseftot and Mishnayot of Masechet Mikvaot down to later halachah and classic responsa. ‘Divrei Yosef’ by R. Ovadiah Yosef Toledano is a wonderful sefer on mikvaot. ‘Torat Moshe’ by R. Moshe Wilner is nice too. (There are plenty of other seforim dealing with all sorts of Mikvaot related topics; you may want to consider specifying a preference in subject matter. [This](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=10298) thread should keep you busy.)